# Delete all records from Odoo model using XMLRPC

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

As per Odoo 10 official documentation, the way to delete data from a model using XMLRPC is:

```py
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'unlink', [[id]])
```

If I want to delete all res.partner records, what shall I use as 'id'?

Answer (score 2):

First browse all the record from the res.partner

```
all_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'res.partner', 'search',[[[]]])
```

Loop 'all_id' and pass the id in the unlink

```
for id in all_id:
    models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'unlink', [[id]])
```

Comment: With this solution you will send one unlink request per record. That isn't really efficient.

Comment: A better solution would be `models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'unlink', [all_id])` without the loop. In my opinion the best solution is to write a method on the server, which will delete all res.partner records. Then you can call this method from the web service api.

Comment: In my opinion the best solution is to write a method on the server, which will delete all res.partner records. Then you can call this method from the web service api. (It will be the pythonic way to write, Thanks for sharing your Idea)

Comment: Why three levels of brackets?

Answer (score 0):

As told in odoo forum:

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'unlink', [])
```

Seems easier.

Another option:

```
search_ids = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'search', [])
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'unlink', search_ids)
```